# Can you help me solve this 2nd order ode?!

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, bessel-functions, differential

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\frac{1}{x}\frac{dy}{dx}-ye^{-x}=0$$ subjected to $y'(1)=-1$ and $y'(a)=0$. I was trying to fit it to the general bessel differential equation. But no luck. :(  :(

Comment: What is the context of this equation?

Comment: @eranreches It's a heat diffusion problem. It arises when you have a space and temperature dependent thermal conductivity in the diffusion equation.

Comment: I'm guessing you might have to resort to a power series method.  If I were to attempt such, I would first translate the equation in $x$ so that the boundary conditions are $y(0) = -1$, $y(a - 1) = 0$; then one may expand about zero as $y = \sum a_i x^i$.  And grind away.  My best guess without too much thought.  Cheers!

Comment: Or use $x=\exp(z)$, so $\frac{d^2y}{dz^2}-\exp(2z-\exp(z))y=0$.  But this doesn't look like it has anything to do with Bessel functions.

Comment: @Three Phi. It should be valuable to write the PDE from which the ODE is derived.

Comment: @RobertLewis Thanks for your comment. I had been able to find a solution for a similar kind of DE except that equation did not have (1/x) in the 2nd term. I had used modified Bessel functions after applying $$z=e^{x}$$ transformation. Hence, I was thinking if I could find any exact solutions via bessel functions.